# Problema con Fecha - Format_UnknownDateTimeWord

Tags: c#, android, string, xamarin, datetime

Estoy tratando de convertir un string a `DateTime` pero no logro lograrlo sin obtener este error:

> Error: Format_UnknownDateTimeWord

**La hora en el string es esta: `12/21/2020 5:24:31 a. m.`**

El código que estoy utilizando es este:

```
TiempoA = VarGlobal.NFFechaHora[position].ToString();
var TiempoAx = Convert.ToDateTime(TiempoA);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es el formato de la fecha:

12/21/2020 5:24:31 a. m.

debería ser:

12/21/2020 5:24:31 AM

Por lo tanto, te sugiero realizar lo siguiente, realizar un "reemplazo" y posteriormente usar `ParseExact()`:

```
TiempoA = VarGlobal.NFFechaHora[position].ToString();

var miFecha = TiempoA.Replace(" a. m.", " AM").Replace(" p. m.", " PM");
        
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(miFecha,"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var TiempoAx = miFecha;
System.Console.WriteLine(TiempoAx);
```

Comment: Hola @Elenasys, lo intente y ahora me da otro error. El string es esto: "12/21/2020 5:24:31 AM" y se logro sortear el error pero ahora me dice: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Ok pero en esta parte del código de tu pregunta ya no muestra el error?, donde muestra el error que linea de código?

Comment: En la 3ra del párrafo que me compartiste. Esta linea =====> DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(miFecha,"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);